# Check if a String is mostly ALL CAPS in PHP

Tags: php, string

What is the best way to see if a string contains *mostly* capital letters?

The string may also contain symbols, spaces, numbers, so would still want it to return true in those cases.

For example: I can check if a strings is ALL-CAPS by something similar to this:

```
if (strtoupper($str) == $str) { /* its true */ }
```

But what if we need to determine if a string is 80% or more ALL-CAPs.

> THE 15 SMALL BROWN FOXES JUMP INTO THE BURNING barn! -> **true**

> The 15 Small Brown Foxes JUMP Into the Burning Barn! -> **false**

I can loop though all the characters, checking them individually, but thats seems a bit wasteful imho.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Count the number of uppercase letters. Divide that by the total length. Test if this is more than the threshold.

Comment: You could use a regexp with `preg_match_all()` to get all the uppercase letters. Sum the length of these to get the total number.

Comment: "I can loop though all the characters, checking them individually, but thats seems a bit wasteful imho." How do you think most functions are implemented internally?
In PHP there's no faster way than to loop the chars imho. In other languages you could get a pointer to the internal bytes and then use CPU instructions to compare 8 bytes at the same time and even that would take a lot of custom code. Don't use Regex if you care about performance.

Comment: Based on comments seems like looping is the only way forward. Thx all so far.

Answer (score 2):

```
$countUppercase = strlen(preg_replace('/[^A-Z]+/', '', $str));
// or: mb_strlen(...)
```

... and then divide by *strlen($str)*

Comment: Seems legit use of a `preg` to me. For better result would just do twice, once for lower, once for upper.

Answer (score 1):

A simple for loop should give the best performance

```
$numUpper = 0;

for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++){
    if (ctype_upper($str[$i])) {
        $numUpper++;
    }
}

return $numUpper;
```

Comment: Or at least a more controlled outcome. Combine with `ctype_alpha` to make a determination and not just count.

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be using [preg_match_all](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) which returns the number of full pattern matches and [mb_strlen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php).

The pattern `\p{Lu}` matches an uppercase letter that has a lowercase variant.

For example:

```
function mostlyUpperInString($s, $threshold) {
    return preg_match_all("/\p{Lu}/u", $s) / mb_strlen($s) > $threshold;
}

function moreUpperThanLower($s, $threshold) {
    return preg_match_all("/\p{Lu}/u", $s) / preg_match_all("/\P{Lu}/u", $s) > $threshold;
}

$strings = [
    "THE 15 SMALL BROWN FOXES JUMP INTO THE BURNING barn!",
    "The 15 Small Brown Foxes JUMP Into the Burning Barn!"
];

foreach ($strings as $str) {
    echo $str . " -> 80% mostlyUpperInString: ". (mostlyUpperInString($str, 0.8) ? "true" : "false") . PHP_EOL;
    echo $str . " -> 80% moreUpperThanLower: ". (moreUpperThanLower($str, 0.8) ? "true" : "false") . PHP_EOL;
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output

```
THE 15 SMALL BROWN FOXES JUMP INTO THE BURNING barn! -> 80% mostlyUpperInString: false
THE 15 SMALL BROWN FOXES JUMP INTO THE BURNING barn! -> 80% moreUpperThanLower: true

The 15 Small Brown Foxes JUMP Into the Burning Barn! -> 80% mostlyUpperInString: false
The 15 Small Brown Foxes JUMP Into the Burning Barn! -> 80% moreUpperThanLower: false
```

See a [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/IvqEd).

Comment: `mostlyUpperInString()` will not work in cases like `YES!!!!!!` because of `mb_strlen()` not differentiating word and non-word characters.

Comment: @Toto Hi there, I think I am missing it.. `mb_strlen` counts a multi byte character as 1 character and `\p{Lu}` matches an uppercase letter. So I would think `YES!!!!!!` leads to `(3/6) > .8` right?

Comment: Sorry, my comment is confusing. Actually, I only wanted to make aware that the definition of the total number of characters in the string can be a: count all characters or b:count only word characters. `YES!!!!!!`  could be a: `3/9` or b: `3/3`. In this answer it is a.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to play around with alternative approaches and came to something like this. Honestly I'd probably just write a loop. Just more clear than something like this and you can omit numbers and other things counted towards "lower case".

Though, with a little massaging of your input you might be able to do something along these lines, simply comparing differences between two strings.

```
<?php
   
isMostlyUpperCase('THE 15 SMALL BROWN FOXES JUMP INTO THE BURNING barn!');
isMostlyUpperCase('The 15 Small Brown Foxes JUMP Into the Burning Barn!');
   
function isMostlyUpperCase($strIn) {
  $strAsUpper = str_split(strtolower($strIn));
  $str = str_split($strIn);
  $diff = array_diff_assoc($str, $strAsUpper);
  return (count($diff) > strlen($strIn) - count($diff)); 
}
```

I've added functional examples based on the other two answers:

```
<?php
    
$str1 = 'THE 15 SMALL BROWN FOXES JUMP INTO THE BURNING barn!';
$str2 = 'The 15 Small Brown Foxes JUMP Into the Burning Barn!';

function pregIsMostlyUpper($str)
{
    $countUppercase = strlen(preg_replace('/[^A-Z]+/', '', $str));
    $countLowercase = strlen(preg_replace('/[^a-z]+/', '', $str));
    return (bool)($countUppercase > $countLowercase);
}

function loopIsMostlyUpper($str)
{
    $numUpper = 0;
    $numLower = 0;
    for ($i = 0;$i < strlen($str);$i++)
    {
        if (ctype_alpha($str[$i]))
        {
            if (ctype_upper($str[$i]))
            {
                $numUpper++;
            } else {
                $numLower++;
            }
        }
    }
    return (bool)($numUpper > $numLower);
}

var_dump(loopIsMostlyUpper($str1));  //true
var_dump(loopIsMostlyUpper($str2));  //false
var_dump(pregIsMostlyUpper($str1));  //true
var_dump(pregIsMostlyUpper($str2));  //false
```

I'll let you time them if you want! Try and beat a sed / awk solution.